# Camel CXF POJO mode using Java DSL

Tags: soap, cxf, apache-camel

I have a pre-existing web service "connect" (SOAP) I would like to call  without using the Swing framework if possible. I have followed the contact first development generating my java files using cxf/wsdl2java tool.

I wish for the userName and password to be extracted from the java object and placed in a SOAP object then sent onot my localhost web service.

When sending the Connect object as a body to the "direct:start" I get an exception...

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Get the wrong parameter size to invoke the out service, Expect size 2, Parameter size 1. Please check if the message body matches the CXFEndpoint POJO Dataformat request.
```

I've checked the first argument is actually an instance of the Connect object passed in.

Do I need some additional annotations in the one of the classes, is the method of testing invalid or
is there an alternative pattern I should follow?

```
public class TestConnectCXF extends CamelTestSupport
{
    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception
    {
        return new RouteBuilder()
        {
            String cxfAddressLine = "cxf:http://localhost:8081/nuxeo/webservices/privateadservice?wsdlURL=wsdl/privateadservice.wsdl" //
                    + "&dataFormat=POJO" //
                    + "&serviceClass=com.sandbox.camelfeed.PrivateAdServiceInterface" //
                    + "&serviceName={http://ws.sandboxtest.com/}PrivateAdService" //
                    + "&synchronous=true" //
                    + "&loggingFeatureEnabled=true" //
                    + "&portName={http://ws.sandboxtest.com/}PrivateAdServiceInterfacePort";
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception
            {
                from("direct:start").to(cxfAddressLine).to("mock:end");
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void testConnectViaPojo() throws InterruptedException
    {
        Connect connectToServer = new Connect();
        connectToServer.setUserName("FakeUser");
        connectToServer.setPassword("scrubbed");
        template.sendBody("direct:start", connectToServer);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

I'm new to camel and web services so any helpful pointers would be greatly appreciated.

**Additional info**

Using camel 2.10, Java 1.6

**Classes generated from wsdl2java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "connect", propOrder = {
   "userName",
   "password"
})
public class Connect {

protected String userName;
protected String password;

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String value) {
    this.userName = value;
}


public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String value) {
    this.password = value;
}
}

@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://ws.sandboxtest.com/", name = "PrivateAdServiceInterface")
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
public interface PrivateAdServiceInterface {

        // Omitted Code relating to other web calls

        @WebResult(name = "return", targetNamespace = "")
        @RequestWrapper(localName = "connect", targetNamespace = "http://ws.sandboxtest.com/", className = "com.sandbox.camelfeed.Connect")
        @WebMethod
        @ResponseWrapper(localName = "connectResponse", targetNamespace = "http://ws.sandboxtest.com/", className = "com.sandbox.camelfeed.ConnectResponse")
        public java.lang.String connect(
            @WebParam(name = "userName", targetNamespace = "")
            java.lang.String userName,
            @WebParam(name = "password", targetNamespace = "")
            java.lang.String password
        ) throws ClientException_Exception;
    }

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {
{
    // Omitted other web calls information
      private final static QName _Connect_QNAME = new QName("http://ws.sandboxtest.com/", "connect");

    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://ws.sandboxtest.com/", name = "connect")
    public JAXBElement<Connect> createConnect(Connect value) {
        return new JAXBElement<Connect>(_Connect_QNAME, Connect.class, null, value);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you able to find a way to implement a solution for this issue ?

Comment: Suggest a customer processor to avoid the 'magic'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience there are some things in Camel, like calling a SOAP Web service or making a REST call, that are easier to do in a custom processor, than using a component like CXF, HTTP or HTTP4.

I usually work with Spring, so I tend to use either Spring REST template or the JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean (for Webservice calls) for outbound calls.

Here is an example using a JAX-WS call:

```
    public class WebServiceProcessorBean {

    @Autowired
    private JAXWSProxy theProxy;


    public void callWebservice(Exchange exchange) {
        Response response = theProxy.call();

        //Do something with the response and Exchange.
    }
  }
```

The definition in the Spring application context:

```
<bean id="theProxyService" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="XXX"/>
        <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="http://xxxxx.wsdl"/>
        <property name="namespaceUri" value="xxxx"/>
        <property name="serviceName" value="xxxx"/>
        <property name="portName" value="xxxxx"/>
</bean>
```

Use the WebServiceProcessorBean defined in Spring application context with beanRef() DSL method.

```
.beanRef("theProxyService", "callWebservice")
```

Answer (score 0):

I try also dig into Apache Camel with CXF:).

I think exception, which is throws, is about problem with number of argument.
 `template.sendBody(what_is_called, input_parameter_s, output_parameter);`

Output parameter is the most probably return value from calling of cxf webservices.