# Camel cxfws producer, POJO format, throws "Get the wrong parameter size to invoke the out service" error

Tags: apache-camel, cxf-client

I have a similar situation as [Camel CXF POJO mode using Java DSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133167/camel-cxf-pojo-mode-using-java-dsl) where

- I have a wsdl https://api.stage.eventcore.com/ReportService.asmx?WSDL
- Created a wsdl2java library
- Using camel cxf producer component, with POJO format to make a SOAP request.
- Setting the `operationname`, `operationnamespace` as headers. `cxfEndpoint` is also configured accurately.

Below is the error I am getting for "GetReport" operation.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Get the wrong parameter size to invoke the out service, Expect size 7, Parameter size 4.
Please check if the message body matches the CXFEndpoint POJO Dataformat request.
```

Here is the binding info for the operation I am dealing with.

```
<wsdl:operation name="GetReport">
<soap:operation soapAction="https://api.eventcore.com/GetReport" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
<soap:header message="tns:GetReportAuthTokenHeader" part="AuthTokenHeader" use="literal"/>
<soap:header message="tns:GetReportCredentialsHeader" part="CredentialsHeader" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
<soap:header message="tns:GetReportAuthTokenHeader" part="AuthTokenHeader" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

As part of the exchange body I am sending a list of objects with CredentialHeader, GetReport Object with necessary data. I also added holder parameters for Response message.

```
GetReport getReport = new GetReport();
getReport.setReportID(123);
getReport.setSortColumn("LastModified");
getReport.setStartRow(1);
getReport.setEndRow(2);
getReport.setSortAscending(true);
ReportFilter filter = new ReportFilter();
filter.setField("LastModified");
filter.setComparison(ComparisonType.GREATER_THAN);
filter.setMatchValue("2018-05-09T23:23:51.8769404Z");
filter.setMode(FilterMode.SELF);
getReport.setFilter(filter);

CredentialsHeader credentials = new CredentialsHeader();
credentials.setUserName("foo");
credentials.setPassword("bar");
credentials.setEventID(11111);

List<Object> params = new ArrayList<Object>();
params.add(getReport);
params.add(credentials);
params.add(null); //params.add(new AuthTokenHeader());
params.add(new javax.xml.ws.Holder<AuthTokenHeader>());
//params.add(new javax.xml.ws.Holder<GetReportResponse>());

exchange.getIn().setBody(params);
```

here is the cxfEndpoint configuration.

```
org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfEndpoint endpoint_cSOAP_1 = getCxfEndpoint(
                "cxf://"
                        + "https://api.stage.eventcore.com/ReportService.asmx"
                        + "?dataFormat=POJO"
                        + "&serviceClass="
                        + "tableau.ea.eventcore.api.reportservice.ReportServiceSoap"
                        + "&serviceName="
                        + "{https://api.eventcore.com/}ReportService"
                        + "&endpointName="
                        + "{https://api.eventcore.com/}ReportServiceSoap"
                        + "&defaultOperationNamespace="
                        + javax.xml.namespace.QName.valueOf(
                                "{https://api.eventcore.com/}GetReport")
                                .getNamespaceURI()
                        + "&defaultOperationName="
                        + javax.xml.namespace.QName.valueOf(
                                "{https://api.eventcore.com/}GetReport")
                                .getLocalPart() + "&" + "loggingFeatureEnabled"
                        + "=" + "true" + "&" + "continuationTimeout" + "="
                        + 600000
                        + "&headerFilterStrategy=#CXF_PAYLOAD_HEADER_FILTER"
                        + "&properties.id=" + "cSOAP_1", false, false, false,
                (String[]) null);
```

What I don't understand is , why cxf expecting 7 parameters? What are those 7 params? I tried making it 7 by adding some nulls, but it fails with "argument type mismatch" error. Please help me understand Input message parts in this particular operation.

Comment: Please show us your POJOs and the CxfEndpoint.

Comment: Thank you for the response. added details to the description.

Answer (score 0):

I did workaround this issue by NOT using "-exsh true" option while generating wsdl, and setting the SOAP headers using Holders.LIST header. While doing that I had to set mustUnderstand = true for CredentialsHeader.

finally I got the headers added to the SOAP request. But, I really want to know why the path of passing all headers plus body as list of parameters ( with "-exsh true" option) didn't work. I had exact same approach working for a different webservice, but not for this one. I am curious what is making the difference.

Pls share if anyone has insight.